# Does the internet runs slower when the display is off?

Tags: 15.04, ubuntu-touch, aquaris

I have an application which runs in background(it connects to internet and does some stuff)  but it seems that when the display is off is works very slow or almost stops. Is this a setting or something in ubuntu touch that I can disable it? Currently I need to tap on the display continously to prevent this which is very annoying.

Comment: That is highly unlikely. Do you mean you physically switch off the display, screensaver starts, or similar?

Comment: It's a phone so I just press the "power" button once and the displays goes dark(though the apps aare still running).

Comment: If I don't press the power button the displays goes off anyway like on any other phone ( to save battery).

Comment: Take a look at the [Active Screen app](https://uappexplorer.com/app/activescreen.mivoligo). Maybe this can help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently the Ubuntu Touch platform does not allow applications to run in the background, or while the screen is off... this is a known limitation of the platform which will be addressed at some point (sorry, I don't know more details, perhaps search launchpad for a bug or log one so that it could be tracked).

As a last ditch workaround you could install an application "Active Screen" to stop the screen from switching off.

Comment: I run the application from the  terminal app and it definitely works "in background" because I switch to other apps and it's still running (i'm checking from the API is connecting to). The issue is only when the display goes  off.   It basically seems that when the display goes off the application is paused. Keeping the display active so that an app can run is so wrong...

Comment: If you open a shell, run "top", then switch to another app for 5 seconds, and switch back to the shell, "top" will be "Stopped", a'la CTRL-Z....

Comment: I'm reliably informed that the phone does go into a low power mode when the screen is off which makes it slower, although personally I've not been able to get any app running with the screen off YMMV.

Comment: I'm afraid you are right... the application is actually frozen in time when you switch the focus. I only experienced some latency effects that made me believe that it's still running but way slower. I also found this which just confirms your answer https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg03774.html

Comment: I spoke to Alan Pope about this, and some system services still run although standard apps don't, and if you talk to one of those you can see that the system runs slower/lower power with the screen off, but in my experience/understanding "click" apps are suspended.... I'm not sure what the plan for this is, but I have a number of related bugs open.

Answer (score 1):

In the battery settings set the "**Sleep when idle**" to **Never**, but it is just temporary solution.

Comment: I confirm it works thus the upvote!